# After filtering data in view model it's not showing/refreshing view

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, combobox

I have  two types of site lists,which I am **filtering** inside view-model by below code

```
  public void FilterSite()
    {
        if (SelectedItem.Contains("EC350"))

            listofsites = new ObservableCollection<SiteDetails>(listofsites.Where(p => Convert.ToString(p.DeviceType) == "MiCell_Ec350"));
        else if (SelectedItem.Contains("MiCell"))
            listofsites = new ObservableCollection<SiteDetails>(listofsites.Where(p => Convert.ToString(p.DeviceType) == "MiCell"));
        else if (SelectedItem.Contains("Mini-Max"))
            listofsites = new ObservableCollection<SiteDetails>(listofsites.Where(p => Convert.ToString(p.DeviceType) == "Mini-Max"));


    }
```

Now for getting automatic updates in **listofsites** I am implementing **InotifyPropertyChanged** and ***OnPropertyChanged*** inside setter of property

```
public class SiteMainUC_VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    private ObservableCollection<SiteDetails> listofsites = null;
    public ObservableCollection<SiteDetails> Listofsites
    {
        get
        {
            return listofsites;
        }
        set
        {
            listofsites = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Listofsites");
        }
    }
```

After combo-box is selecting value, by debugging I am seeing filtered values but view is not showing. Now for  binding I have  tried oneway/twoway both but not working. Below is xaml code-

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbSiteSearch" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding SearchFilter,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Height="18" Width="18" IsReadOnly="True" FontFamily="Arial"   >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ComboBox.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/MasterLink;component/Resources/i_filter.png"    />
                </ComboBox.Background>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="All" Height="34" Width="190" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="EC350" Height="34" Width="190" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Mini-Max" Height="34" Width="190" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12"/>
            </ComboBox>
```

Now for sitelist listbox code I have

```
<ListBox    ItemsSource="{Binding Listofsites}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Selectedsites, Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Height="600" 
          SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" >
```

Comment: With an Observable collection you don't have to implement the OnPropertyChanged, instead you should use Collection.Clear(). And add all the new items to the collection like Collection.Add(filteredItem)

Comment: Tried. But not getting.

Comment: Have you done same notify thing on child view model also i.e. SiteDetails

Comment: No, have not as that is api [dll] given by client from where all the data's are coming for this application. 

Since you said I''ll  try. Thanx for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void FilterSite()
    {
     listofsites = new ObservableCollection<SiteDetails>(parameters);

if (SelectedItem.Contains("EC350"))

            Listofsites = new ObservableCollection<SiteDetails>(listofsites.Where(p => Convert.ToString(p.DeviceType) == "MiCell_Ec350"));
        else if (SelectedItem.Contains("MiCell"))
            Listofsites = new ObservableCollection<SiteDetails>(listofsites.Where(p => Convert.ToString(p.DeviceType) == "MiCell"));
        else if (SelectedItem.Contains("Mini-Max"))
            Listofsites = new ObservableCollection<SiteDetails>(listofsites.Where(p => Convert.ToString(p.DeviceType) == "Mini-Max"));


    }
```

1)Inside filter method add private varibles to bind it with observable collection, otherwise once you filter your value, it's values will be  null and  by clicking 2nd time you won't get any value changes there by filtering.

2)Sometimes assigning private variables here ***listofsites*** won't give you desired results and there will be  problem with communicating through view to viewmodel. Though it's a bad  style of coding but it's shortcut and  usefull to use direct  property names instead of variables, I,e; ***Listofsites***

3)I also have faced this kind of similar view refresh issues several time. For better style you should go for ***MessageBus*** architecture style. Publish/subscribe style can be implemented for communicating with vm to vm or vm to view.

link belowhttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647328.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bind your ComboBox's ItemsSource to the underlying collection. Your XAML should look something like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbSiteSearch" Height="18" Width="18" 
          IsReadOnly="True" FontFamily="Arial"
          Text="{Binding SearchFilter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Listofsites}"/>
```

Comment: Already listbox [all site list] contains `ItemsSource="{Binding Listofsites}"` ,that's why  if I put same thing for combobox,it's giving error.

Comment: Still hard to understand the problem without the full context. Are you sure you set DataContext correctly? In the FilterSite() method you assign a value to a listofsites  field instead of a Listofsites property, which doesn't result in OnPropertyChanged call.